# Rvalue references in g++

Tags: c++

I'm changing the compiler from Visual Studio to g++, and having some problems with pass by reference in function arguments.

In Visual Studio, the function is:

```
void Foo(int&a, int&b)
```

So that a, b are modified in this function. Therefore I can't use in g++

```
void Foo(const int&a, const int &b)
```

And also rvalue reference is not allowed in my g++:

```
void Foo( int&& a, int&& b)
```

So is using pointer is the only way to convert the code?

```
void Foo( int* a, int* b)
```

P/S: This is the error when compiling with g++:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Steerable::buildSCFpyrLevs(Tensor<double, 2ul>, std::vector<Tensor<double, 2ul> >&, int&, int&, int&, bool&)’
Steerable.cpp:63:100: note: candidate is:
Steerable.h:93:7: note: void Steerable::buildSCFpyrLevs(Steerable::data_ref, std::vector<Tensor<double, 2ul> >&, int, int, int, bool)
Steerable.h:93:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Tensor<double, 2ul>’ to ‘Steerable::data_ref {aka Tensor<double, 2ul>&}’
```

And the function declarations are:

```
typedef Tensor<value_type,2> data_type;
typedef data_type& data_ref;


vector<Steerable::data_type>& Steerable::buildSCFpyr(Steerable::c_data_ref im, int nLevel, int nDir, int twidth, bool subsample)
```

The line which has the error:

```
buildSCFpyrLevs(imdft.FreqComplexFilter(toComplex(lo0mask)),pyr_freq,nLevel,nDir,twidth, subsample);
```

Comment: Why doesn't the first work?

Comment: Er, what are you trying to do? Convert the code *to do what*?

Comment: As for the second, I guess you could use `const int&`. Otherwise, you will also have to change the calling code

Comment: "Therefore I can't use in g++": wrong. You *can* use it. Just not with temporaries.

Comment: I'm having the original code in Visual Studio, and want to compile it in Ubuntu for integration with other programs. For some reasons, the first line doesn't compile successfully. I'll post the debug screen now.

Comment: I'm going with @juanchopanza and saying that your code passes a temporary as a non-const reference. You said the arguments have to be modified, so why are you passing in a temporary? If you want to modify something, make it something you can actually use after.

Comment: By the way, how old *is* your GCC? Rvalue references were supported as of GCC 4.3, so if they're not allowed in yours, yours is pretty old.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I make a simpler/clearer question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191952/pass-by-reference. Sorry for this confusing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FreqComplexFilter` probably doesn't return by reference.

**A dirty fix:**

```
Tensor<double, 2> tempVal = imdft.FreqComplexFilter(toComplex(lo0mask));
buildSCFpyrLevs(tempVal, pyr_freq, nLevel, nDir, twidth, subsample);
```

It's dirty because it just makes the code compile, it doesn't fix the underlying design problem (The question is why `buildSCFpyrLevs` is modifying the temporary value returned by `FreqComplexFilter`).

Comment: Thank you it works! Can you explain more, why when I put the whole function in buildSCFpyrLevs, it doesn't work?

Comment: @DzungNguyen I'm not entirely sure about the inner workings of the compilers, but I know that `FreqComplexFilter` implicitly returns a temporary value (temporary because its scope is limited to the expression) and that passing a temporary value by reference should be avoided whenever possible since [this may lead to unexpected behaviour](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/44221/) and g++ forcing this behaviour is good in my opinion.