# Pass by reference

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this code? This is a simplified version of what I'm doing. It's a recursive function calls on the same variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Foo(int& x)
{
    x++;
    Foo(x);
    cout<<x<<"\n";
    if(x==10)
        return;
}

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    Foo(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, what **is** wrong with this code?

Comment: The exit condition should come *before* the recursive call; not after.

Comment: I'm guessing you never tried stepping through this algorithm in a debugger to see exactly what your code was doing.  If you did, you probably would have figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

This function does not have a termination condition, it just calls itself unconditionally, trying to set up an infinite recursion:

```
void Foo(int& x)
{
    x++;
    Foo(x); // <==== UNCONDITIONALLY RECURSIVE
    cout<<x<<"\n";
    if(x==10)
        return;
}
```

Since a stack frame for each function call takes some memory space, an infinite recursion is not possible: sooner or later, your stack will grow beyond its limit size and your program will be forced to terminate.

Comment: ...and so it runs out of stack space.  Otherwise one might think it would just run forever.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Correct. I just took that for granted. Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
x++;
Foo(x);
cout<<x<<"\n";
if(x==10)
    return;
```

The problem is that this will cause infinite recursion. You only check `if (x == 10)` **after** the function calls itself, so it cannot possibly get to the return condition. Fix this by writing

```
x++;
if(x==10)
    return;

Foo(x);
cout<<x<<"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite recursion. It will keep creating stack frames until stack space is exhausted. You need an exit guard before your recursive invocation:

```
void Foo(int& x)
{
    cout<<x<<"\n";
    if(x==10)
        return;
    x++;
    Foo(x);
}
```